# Asp Web.Api data filter based on DTO

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I've architecure question. I've Restfull api accompanied with ddd and i thinking what is the best approach to allow user to filter data (i am using nhibarnate as ORM).

I want to allow user to write query string example:

> ?productName=test&orderId=2

So far i doing this using custom attributes placed on DTO (properties that can be filter) and under the hood it's translated to criteria API (using refletion and some strange tricks..)

I've read about OData but if i understand corectly its based on IQuerable (and have bad support for nHibernate).

What is your opinion about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aspnet Web API OData also exposes ODataQueryOptions. You can model bind the OData query to an ODataQueryOptions to get an AST (abstract syntax tree) representation of the query which you can then traverse to translate to an nHibernate query methods.